# Using the narrator in C# windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, text-to-speech

the narrator API (System.Speech) is not available for windows store.
Is there an alternative API or method for using this?
I found that there is a text-to-speech function as part of the [Microsoft translator service](http://translatorservice.codeplex.com/), however since the narrator is already available, it would be silly to have to use this service for that, so I'd rather use it directly if possible.

I thought of maybe running a command through CMD.exe to text-to-speech something, but in windows store apps it's impossible to launch external processes, also I haven't found a command line interface for the narrator anyway.

Does anybody know of any method of doing this?

Comment: Just FYI: I wouldn't use the terminology "Narrrator API", you won't see Microsoft representing it as such in documentation. Microsoft Narrator is a discrete assistive technology tool. The SpeechSynthesis API as referenced in the MSDN sample mentioned in the current answer is intended for performing speech synthesis in Windows Store apps. The connection between Narrator and the API is either indirect or nonexistent.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8.1 has offline text to speech support. [Here's MSDN sample.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Speech-synthesis-sample-6e07b218)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement accessibility? If so, then this may be what your looking for: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.automation.automationproperties

You can set the Name attached property to whatever you would like to have read.